# Анимация CSS, плавное изменение цвета текста

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Нужно плавное изменение цвета текста, 5-6 цветов друг за другом.
"Эффект гирлянды"

Comment: Хорошая задумка, но увидеть бы хоть часть кода который вы уже сделали на пути к этой гирлянде.

Comment: Нужно, сделай, кто мешает...???

Answer (score 2):

Я хочу продемонстрировать работу плагина на jquery : [lettering.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js) который разбивает слово на буквы которыми можно манипулировать и так же манипулировать задержкой анимации

В сниппете stackoverflow я на прямую вставил этот весь lettering

```js
(function($) {
  function injector(t, splitter, klass, after) {
    var text = t.text(),
      a = text.split(splitter),
      inject = '';
    if (a.length) {
      $(a).each(function(i, item) {
        inject += '<span class="' + klass + (i + 1) + '" aria-hidden="true">' + item + '</span>' + after;
      });
      t.attr('aria-label', text)
        .empty()
        .append(inject)

    }
  }


  var methods = {
    init: function() {

      return this.each(function() {
        injector($(this), '', 'char', '');
      });

    },

    words: function() {

      return this.each(function() {
        injector($(this), ' ', 'word', ' ');
      });

    },

    lines: function() {

      return this.each(function() {
        var r = "eefec303079ad17405c889e092e105b0";
        injector($(this).children("br").replaceWith(r).end(), r, 'line', '');
      });

    }
  };

  $.fn.lettering = function(method) {
    // Method calling logic
    if (method && methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (method === 'letters' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 0)); // always pass an array
    }
    $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.lettering');
    return this;
  };

})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#text").lettering();
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.char1,
.char2,
.char3,
.char4,
.char5,
.char6,
.char7,
.char8 {
  animation: color 3s infinite;
}

.char1 {
  animation-delay: -0.1s;
}

.char2 {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.char3 {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}

.char4 {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.char5 {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}

.char6 {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.char7 {
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
}

.char8 {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }
  25% {
    color: green;
  }
  50% {
    color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Анимация</p>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Та же ситуация без использования этого плагина

```css
p {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.char1,
.char2,
.char3,
.char4,
.char5,
.char6,
.char7,
.char8 {
  animation: color 3s infinite;
}

.char1 {
  animation-delay: -0.1s;
}

.char2 {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.char3 {
  animation-delay: -0.3s;
}

.char4 {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.char5 {
  animation-delay: -0.5s;
}

.char6 {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.char7 {
  animation-delay: -0.7s;
}

.char8 {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }
  25% {
    color: green;
  }
  50% {
    color: blue;
  }
  75% {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="char1">А</span>
  <span class="char2">н</span>
  <span class="char3">и</span>
  <span class="char4">м</span>
  <span class="char5">а</span>
  <span class="char6">ц</span>
  <span class="char7">и</span>
  <span class="char8">я</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж фамилия заканчивается на ян, так  быть отвечу.

```css
@keyframes anime {
    0% {
        color: orange;
    }
    33% {
        color: red;
    }
    66% {
        color: blue;
    }
    100% {
        color: orange;
    }
}


h2 {
    animation: anime infinite 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
```

Что бы было понятно что вы пытались сами а не что за вас нужно писать, в следующий раз задавая вопрос показывайте свой код.